# ng-repeat in directive with filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

after clicking on the "+" array is not correctly sorted in directive.

I want two lists: first with type "a", and second with type "b".

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Vkd/

```
code already on jsFiddle
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Vkd/1/

```
<textarea ng-model="input.value"></textarea>
```

just rename ng-model on input.value